# Canvas manipulation event not firing until after first try

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8, swipe

I'm trying to animate a canvas by swiping using ´ManipulationDelta`.
The problem is simple. when I run the app, the only time the manipulation event is not fired is at the first try. If I tap (or swipe) anywhere in the canvas once, then the second time it works until the application is restarted.

This is my XAML code:

```
<Canvas Name="rootCanvas" Style="{StaticResource rootCanvas}" Hold="rootCanvas_Hold" ManipulationDelta="rootCanvas_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationCompleted="rootCanvas_ManipulationCompleted">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="menuAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="rootAnimation" d:IsOptimized="True" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Canvas Name="rootAnimation">
        <Grid x:Name="rootContainer" DataContext="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource rootContainer}">
            ...
        </grid>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

And this is my code in C#

```
private void rootCanvas_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X > 25 && !menu.IsMenuOpen())
    {
        MoveViewWindow(150);
        hintActive = false;
        menu.SetMenuOpen();
        return;
    }
    else if (e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X < (-25) && menu.IsMenuOpen())
    {
        MoveViewWindow(0);
        hintActive = false;
        menu.SetMenuClosed();
        return;
    }
}

private void rootCanvas_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (!menu.IsMenuOpen())
    {
        hintActive = true;
        MoveViewWindow(25);
    }
    return;
}
```

I have a `rootCanvas_ManipulationCompleted` where the breakpoint gets hit even if the ManipulationDelta and Hold breakpoints aren't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess: Could be a focus issue, have you tried setting focus initially one time in code to the canvas and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: @robbievercammen did you solve this issue?

Comment: @JTIM, sorry but I don't have access to this code anymore. I remember playing around with manipulation events. The only thing I remember is, this code works. It was a small issue that made the animation go haywire.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command:

```
rootCanvas.Focus();
```

This will set focus to the canvas you are hitting, just pop this event in the load method of the page.